# Is there any way to get data from an other component using output decorator with mouseover event?

Tags: angular, typescript, output, decorator, angular11

I have two component and passing data from on component to another component using output decorator.
here I need to get data on mouse over.

here is my child component code

```
 <pro-filter-pipe class="w-100" [getRoute]="routerUrl" (pipeLineMode)="getHeadingString($event)"
        [getLeadsCounts]="leadsLength" (projectType)="getProjectType($event)" (URL)="getURL($event)"
        (showIcon)="iconCondition($event)" (Description)="getDescription($event)" (IconDescription)="getDescriptionIcon($event) ">
    </pro-filter-pipe>
```

Comment: you mean where mouse hover your child component?

Comment: its mean when i move mouse on my child component it pass the data to Parent ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have an `EventEmitter` with `@Output` decorator which will `emit` an event upon `mouseover` event. Basically it's the same as when you want to `emit` some data upon user clicking on button.

**Parent Component HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper" (onMouseHover)="foo($event)"></div>
```

**Parent Component TS:**

```
class Parent {
    foo(data) {
        // Do something with the data sent by the child component!
    }
}
```

**Child Component TS:**

```
export class ChildComponent{
    @Output() onMouseHover = new EventEmitter<any>();
    data: any;

    onMouseHover(someData) {
      this.onMouseHover.emit(someData);
    }
 }
```

**Child Component HTML:**

```
<div (mouseover)="onMouseHover(data)">
</div>
```

Good idea would be to put this event on parent `div` or other container `HTML` tag that holds your child component `template`.

It is basic child to parent component communication using `@Output` and `EventEmitter`.

Comment: I have updated the above answer, it is in review. If anyone has enough reputation kindly review it and review/reject the changes.

Answer (score 0):

put `(mousehover)` event on the wrapper tag of `ChildComponent`
like this:

`<div class="container" (childMousehover)="doSome()"> ...</div>`

and fire the event up from this function with your data:

```
 export class ChildComponent{
    @Output() childMouseHover: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
    someData;

    doSome() {
      this.childMouseHover.emit(this.someData)
    }

  }`
```

and in the parent element:
`<app-child (childMousehover)="onHover($event)"> </app-child>`
and you get the data from the `$event`